# Usage of the word “particular”

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context

Why did the writer use the word **"particular"** in this definition of **government** that has taken from the Oxford dictionary?

> "a particular system or method of controlling a country".

Can we say **"a  system or method of controlling a country"** instead of that?

Comment: Can you make a full sentence to make the question clearer?

Comment: @Jan It's already a full sentence. It's actually a definition that I found in this link https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/government?q=government

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can say "a system or method of controlling a country" instead.

The reason the dictionary uses the word 'particular' is to emphasize the idea that each system of controlling a country is separate and distinct from each other system of controlling a country. There is not just one kind of system for doing this. There are many. Any government you describe is just one of many kinds of systems or methods of controlling a country.

Answer (score -1):

Example:

A government is a **particular** system or method of controlling a country.

Communism is a system or method of controlling a country.

Put another way, communism would be a "particular" method of governing a country, and this is probably the reason why the writer chose to use the word *particular*. A government is the general idea of a system that controls a country. Communism, for example, is one **particular** form of government.